# EC2 instance billing type programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have reservation of type `t2.micro` and `us-ease-1d` availability zone, also I have multiple instances running, including the one with mentioned type and zone.

As a result I expect billing for this one instance will take into account the reservation. The problem is that I haven't found any link between reservation and actual instances.

I've used `aws ec2 describe-instances` and `aws ec2 describe-reserved-instances` CLI commands but I wasn't able to find any link.

Is it possible to realise which billing approach will be used for each instance using Amazon SDK?

So  f.e. I will see that some instance is linked to some reserved instance (reservation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to realise which billing approach will be used for each instance using Amazon SDK?

No, it isn't.

The "link" between reserved instances and running instances is not something the EC2 operational infrastructure knows about.  It's all done after the fact, in billing.

Each hour, for a given instance type and availability zone placement,  you're billed for your reserved instances (depending on the terms of the reservation, this happens whether you have this many instances running or not, though in some cases, the amount billed here is $0 since you've already paid). Then, if the number of running on-demand instances for that type and placement exceeds exceeds the number of reserved instances for that type and placement, the difference for that hour is billed at the on-demand rate.

So if you had purchased one reserved instance matching a certain spec and during a given hour you had two such instances running, it's not really the case that one of your instances "is the reserved instance" and the other one isn't.  If you stop either one, then the next hour, the reserved instance pricing applies to the one that remains running... but EC2 can't tell you which is which and, in fact, the billing logic is such that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a link between reservations and specific instances. Think of it more like a discount that gets applied to your bill, after you have incurred some instance charges.

You can use the [Reserved Instance Utilization Report](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/usage-reports-ri.html) to see how your reservations have been applied to the instance hours you have been charged for.